# Why does this program give me a "segmentation fault"?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So my brother was making a program to turn all words in a string to hashtag, but for some reason it always gives a "segmentation fault" error at the end of execution. I tried to find what may cause it, but haven't found. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* setHashtag(char text[10000])
{
    int i, j;

    printf("Initial text = %s\n", text);

    for (i = 9998; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        text[i+1] = text[i];
    }
    text[0] = ' ';

    for (i = 0; text[i+1] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == ' ' && text[i+1] != ' ')
        {
            for (j = 9998; j > i; j--)
            {
                text[j+1] = text[j];
            }
            text[i+1] = '#';

            printf("Partial text = %s\n", text);
        }
    }

    return text;
}

void execute() {
    char text[5000], textFinal[10000];

    gets(text);

    strcpy(textFinal, setHashtag(text));
    printf("%s\n", textFinal);
}

int main()
{
    execute();
    printf("Back to main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You pass an array of size `5000` into your function, yet you access `10000` elements inside. Of course, it will crash.

This size of the array specified in function declaration does not matter. It is ignored by the compiler. This

```
char* setHashtag(char text[10000])
```

is equivalent to this

```
char* setHashtag(char *text)
```

i.e. the function receives a pointer to the beginning of your original argument array, not a new local copy of the argument array (naked arrays in C are not copyable).

This means that when you call your function as

```
char text[5000];
...
setHashtag(text)
```

the `text` array does not magically become a `char [10000]` array. It remains a `char [5000]` array, as it was originally declared. Attempting to access `text[9998]` and such inside the function leads to undefined behavior.

Since your `setHashtag` function expects a fixed size array of size `10000`, it might be a better idea to declare your function as

```
char* setHashtag(char (*text)[10000])
```

and pass in the array arguments as `setHashing(&text)`. This will make sure you will not be able to pass in an array of wrong size. Inside the function you'll have to access the array as `(*text)[i]`.

Comment: I thought it would copy all text to a new array, thanks for explanation!